# -bash: datalab: command not found

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I installed the cloud datalab component by running `gcloud components install datalab`

However, I keep getting the following error from my terminal when attempting to create a datalab instance:
`-bash: datalab: command not found`

[image]

When I run `gcloud components list`, I get that I have correctly installed `datalab` as evidenced in the image below:
[image]

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the script under your sdk root? I can find mine under `~/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/datalab`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output of `gcloud components list` you have already installed the `datalab` command line tool. The binary should be present at this location: `$GOGOLE_CLOUD_SDK_INSTALL_DIR/bin/datalab`

If running just `datalab` still does not invoke this binary, then you do not have the Cloud SDK bin directory in your `$PATH` environment variable.

To confirm this theory, verify if you are able to run `datalab` by providing its full path.

Example (assuming your Cloud SDK is installed at `~/google-cloud-sdk`):

```
~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/datalab
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and I was able to fix the issue by reinstalling Google Cloud SDK following [this instruction](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) and try again.

Make sure to delete the original gcloud command before reinstalling because it may be installed in a different path.

I use Debian, and gcloud command was originally under /usr/local/bin/gcloud, which had that issue. (I don't remember how I installed the command.) When I followed [the instruction](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/), it was installed at /usr/bin/gcloud and it worked fine, though it instructed me to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-datalab
```

instead of:

```
$ gcloud components install datalab
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and found the following code in my bash profile was pointing to the wrong installation folder (presumably after I decided to update or re-install in a different way than I had done originally), changing to the correct location (find by using gcloud info) fixed it:

```
\# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then source '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

\# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then source '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi
```